# Как поменять цвет иконки фейсбук в svg спрайте

Tags: svg, svg-спрайт, спрайт

Помогите пожалуйста советом.  У меня svg иконка  фейсбук
добавлена через спрайт в HTML. В CSS пишу стили, как  поменять цвет самой букве в иконке? Изначально все стили сброшены.

```
.social__img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  fill: $gray;
}

<svg class="social__img ">
  <use xlink:href="images/sprite.svg#footer-facebook"></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: через css filter ....

Comment: Спасибо большое )

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ ,возможно не верно задала вопрос там получилось немного иначе .Напишу как решила проблему, Может кому то будет в помощь )  .Ссылкам на иконки задала цвет , размеры и радиус ( если нужно ) а уже самим иконкам fill и  stroke ,стили которые можно менять при наведении .Результат , когда наводишь на ссылку у нее меняется фон и меняется fill и stroke у иконки.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на RuSO! Добавьте код в этот ответ, как вы реализовали свои идеи. Это будет полезно  другим участникам. Кстати, в вопрос я добавил тег svg-спрайт, где много аналогичных вопросов и ответов.